# Accurate range of number of keys in the table

Tags: java

I have to return the number of keys in the table within the range [key1, key2], so for an example in a string of keys of "BEIOU" the range is from "B" and "U" it should return 5 since there are 5 keys in-between "B" and "U". My current program however returns 4. If I test the same string "BEIOU" but the range is from "A" to "Z" then it returns 5 as there are 5 keys in between, but for "B" and "U", it returns 4. How may I fix this?

```
public class SortedArrayST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
    private static final int MIN_SIZE = 2;
    private Key[] keys;     
    private Value[] vals;  
    private int N = 0;  

    public SortedArrayST() {
        this(MIN_SIZE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SortedArrayST(int size) {
        keys = (Key[])(new Comparable[size]);
        vals = (Value[])(new Object[size]);
    }

    public SortedArrayST(Key[] keys, Value[] vals) {
        this(keys.length < MIN_SIZE ? MIN_SIZE : keys.length);
        N = (keys.length == vals.length ? keys.length : 0);
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < N && keys[i].compareTo(keys[i - 1]) > 0; i++);
        if (i < N) { // input is not sorted
            System.err.println("SortedArrayST(Key[], Value[]) constructor error:");
            System.err.println("Given keys array of size " + N + " was not sorted!");
            System.err.println("Initializing an empty symbol table!");
            N = 0;
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                this.keys[i] = keys[i];
                this.vals[i] = vals[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public int countRange(Key key1, Key key2) {
        int firstkey = 0;
        int secondkey = 0;
        int count = 0;
        if(key1.compareTo(key2)>0) {
            firstkey = rank(key1);
            secondkey = rank(key2);
            count = (firstkey - secondkey + 1);
        }
        else if(key2.compareTo(key1)>0) {
            secondkey = rank(key2);
            firstkey = rank(key1);
            count = (secondkey - firstkey + 1);
        }
        return count;
    
    }

    public int rank(Key key) {
         int lo = 0, hi = N-1; 
            while (lo <= hi) { 
                int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2; 
                int cmp = key.compareTo(keys[mid]);
                if      (cmp < 0) hi = mid - 1; 
                else if (cmp > 0) lo = mid + 1; 
                else return mid; 
            } 
            return lo;
        } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        allCountRangeTests();
}
    public static void allCountRangeTests() {
        testCountRange("BEIOU","13456", "B","U", 5);   
        testCountRange("BEIOU","13456", "U","B", 5);  
        testCountRange("BEIOU","13456", "A","Z",5);  
        testCountRange("BEIOU","13456", "C","P",3);   
    }
    
    public static SortedArrayST<String,String> from (String keyData, String valData) {
        int n = keyData.length();
        if ( n != valData.length()) throw new NullPointerException(" from: mismatch sizes");
        String[] keys = new String[n];
        String[] vals = new String[n];
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++ ) {
            keys[i] = keyData.substring(i, i+1); 
            vals[i] = valData.substring(i, i+1);  
        }
        return new SortedArrayST(keys,vals);
    }

    public static void testCountRange( String keyData, String valData, String key1,String key2, int expected) {
        SortedArrayST<String, String> x = from(keyData,valData);
        int actual = x.countRange(key1,key2);
        if ( actual == expected)  // test passes
            StdOut.format("countRangeTest: Correct  Keys: %s, key1: %s  key2: %s     actual: %d expected: %d\n", keyData, key1,key2, actual,expected);
        else
            StdOut.format("countRangeTest: *Error*  Keys: %s, key1: %s  key2: %s     actual: %d expected: %d\n", keyData, key1,key2, actual,expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `rank(Key)` implemented?

Comment: public class SortedArrayST<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {
 private static final int MIN_SIZE = 2;
 private Key[] keys;      // the keys array
 private Value[] vals;    // the values array
 private int N = 0;       // size of the symbol table,

Comment: Not helpful enough. Can you update your question to add more details?

Comment: Sorry the rank implementation is here

Comment: What is a `Key`?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems, which together could explain your results.  First, your two lines:

```
count = secondkey - firstkey;
```

should be:

```
count = secondkey - firstkey + 1;
```

as there is one key in any range X..X, not 0.  That explains why you get '4' when you expect to get '5'.  But that also means you're going to get '6' when you're getting '5' now.  So there's something else wrong....

If in your `rank` method, if you ever drop out of the `while` loop, then you will return `lo`, which is now `> hi`, so you will return a number which is one too high.  In that case, you want to return `hi`.  Your binary search otherwise seems ok from sight.  Not having all of your code, I can't actually run anything.

Comment: Hello, Ive updated the code above so you can test it. I have tried adding +1 and changing the return to hi, but that didn't seem to fix the output of being 1 higher than it should be.